# mmap same file, same physical memory?

Tags: c, linux, mmap

Suppose I:

1. `open` a read-only file `F` of `N` byte length from a process `A`
2. `mmap` its `fd` read-only (`PROT_READ`) and `MAP_SHARED`
3. `mlock` the returned memory range.
4. go into an infinite loop.

My understanding is the data from the file is now resident and backed by `N` bytes of physical memory pages, due to the `mlock`.  The read performance of the memory range should be the same as normal memory allocated with, say, `malloc`.

Now, if I create a second process `B` while the process `A` is still running and do exactly the same steps from process `B`, will the `N` bytes of physical memory pages that back the mmaped file be the same physical pages from process `A`?

That is, will `A` and `B` together use `N` bytes of physical memory?  Or will they use `2*N` bytes of physical memory?

Comment: Basically, yes. See [`vmtouch`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/vmtouch) for a command that does this intentionally.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Are you trying to say that other processes call `mmap` _unintentionally_?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin No, I am saying that `vmtouch -l` intentionally 1) `open()`'s, 2) `mmap()`s, 3) `mlock()`s and 4) "goes into an infinite loop"/waits indefinitely, precisely as OP described, for precisely one of the effects OP was wondering about: Allowing other processes to use this memory knowing it has been prefaulted in.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist It makes sense to me now, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you map a file the pages come from the kernel page cache which maintains the kernel view of the file. There is only ever one view of the same file in the kernel. When you map the file more than once (regardless from which process), the mapped pages are the very same physical pages from the kernel page cache.

Otherwise, it would be prohibitively expensive to maintain different pages of memory in sync when one process modifies its `MAP_SHARED` file mapping.

In other words, processes `A` and `B` together share the same `N` bytes of physical memory used to map the same file.

Answer (score 0):

In modern operating systems, when 2 programs map the same file, each process has its own page table for its memory, that may point to pages of physical memory shared with other user and kernel processes.

With `MAP_SHARED`, this mapping is shared: updates to the mapping are visible to other processes that map this file, and are carried through to the underlying file. The file may not actually be updated until `msync` or `munmap()` is called.